# URL and Site title outputting on Login page

Tags: customization, login

After the body tag, Wordpress is outputting the site url & site name in the Login page (wp-login.php). I think do_action( 'login_head' ); is responsible somehow but not sure how to modify this without touching the core file.

**Update**

While browsing through the functions.php file, i discovered the code below and there where filters echoing the problematic text. Commented the echos out and woohoo. Done

```
if ( !function_exists( 'jh_wp_login_url' ) ) {
function jh_wp_login_url() {
    //echo home_url();
}
```

}
    add_filter('login_headerurl', 'jh_wp_login_url');

```
if ( !function_exists( 'jh_wp_login_title' ) ) {
function jh_wp_login_title() {
    //echo get_option('blogname');
}
```

}
    add_filter('login_headertitle', 'jh_wp_login_title');

Comment: What plug-ins do you have installed? This doesn't occur on a clean install of WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the logo, you could hook into `login_head` and output css that replaces the default logo. This goes into your functions.php.

```
function my_custom_login_logo() {
    // as below or link to an external .css-file
    echo '<style type="text/css">
              div#login h1 a { 
                  background-image:url('urltoyourlogo.png') 
              }
    </style>';
}

add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login_logo');
```